# Spell-checker for LaTeX documents

Tags: latex, spell-checker

I am looking for a program that can perform spell-checking for a LaTeX document that comprises several .tex files and one .bib.

If possible:

- free
- Windows 7
- grammar checking too
- GUI

Answer (score 6):

[TexStudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) is a LaTeX editor with built-in spell checker.

- free / open-source
- cross-platform (QT based)
- powerful editor with code completion
- built-in PDF viewer
- `Tools` - `Check Spelling` or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
- unfortunately you have to check files one by one

[image]